# Angular $scope is not refreshing in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
Service.getData( $scope.data
    function( data ) // success
    {
        $scope.data = {
        schedule:data.value,
            };
}
```

On click of edit button this function will call and text box value will update (schedule:data.value,)

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="data.schedule" class="span12" ng-maxlength="5" maxlength="5" required  ng-pattern="/\d+/" />
```

**It is working in other browsers except IE-10**

If we edit a value in text box and save and then again click on edit it will show old value in IE 10

Please suggest

I tried with below code but not working

```
$scope.data.schedule.push($scope.data.schedule);
$('#someid').val($scope.data.schedule);
$scope.data.schedule = '' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a fix for this ,its working fine in all browsers ,but not sure is a right fix

```
var fetch_timestamp = function() { return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))};

var timestamp = fetch_timestamp();

url = url + '&t='+timestamp;
```

This will clear the cache(it wont take from browser )